Meu projeto está com esse erro: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
Tenho uma aplicação usando Spring boot e PostgresSQL.
Estou tentando configurar o tenant mas está dando erro no Bean. Já tentei sobreescrever e renomear o bean e continua com erro.
Properties
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.persistence.provider=org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
spring.pulsar.client.service-url=pulsar://localhost:6650
spring.pulsar.client.authentication-mode=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/market
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.datasource.tenant1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant1_db
spring.datasource.tenant1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tenant1.username=root
spring.datasource.tenant1.password=password1

spring.datasource.tenant2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant2_db
spring.datasource.tenant2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tenant2.username=root
spring.datasource.tenant2.password=password2 


Classes de config:
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new AbstractRoutingDataSource() {
            @Override
            protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
                return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
            }
        };

        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put("tenant1", createDataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/market_db"));
        targetDataSources.put("tenant2", createDataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tenant2_db"));

        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(createDataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/default_db"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource(String url) {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, TenantIdentifierResolver tenantIdentifierResolver) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.market.model");
        
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.multiTenancy", "DATABASE");
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", tenantIdentifierResolver);
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.persistence.provider", "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider");

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MultiTenantConfig {

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryMultiTenant")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                       TenantIdentifierResolver tenantIdentifierResolver) throws HibernateException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.market.model");

        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.multiTenancy", "DATABASE");
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", tenantIdentifierResolver);

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}

Log do erro:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-12-04T10:27:26.422-03:00 ERROR 20920 --- [marketList] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/market/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:288) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]

meu pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>marketList</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>marketList</name>
    <description>Supermarket shopping</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-pulsar</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

